Insert new row and update old one if some if their columns are matching
My table looks kinda like this:
CREATE TABLE `documents` 
(
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `PERSON_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `DOC_TYPE` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `DOC_INVALIDITY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `DOC_INVALIDITY_DATE` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `ACTUAL` int(11) NOT NULL
)

(`ID`, `PERSON_ID`, `DOC_TYPE`, `DOC_INVALIDITY_ID`, `DOC_INVALIDITY_DATE`, `ACTUAL`) 
(1, 100, 1, 0, NULL, 1),
(2, 100, 2, 0, NULL, 1),
(3, 200, 1, 0, NULL, 1),
(4, 200, 3, 0, NULL, 1);

I need that when adding a new record, update DOC_INVALIDITY to 1, DOC_INVALIDITY_DATE to sysdate and ACTUAL to 0 of an existing record where PERSON_ID and DOC_TYPE coincide with the new record being added.
If there is no such record in the table, then just do a regular INSERT
INSERT INTO documents (ID, PERSON_ID, DOC_TYPE, DOC_INVALIDITY, DOC_INVALIDITY_DATE, ACTUAL) 
VALUES (5, 1, 1, 0, null, 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DOC_INVALIDITY = 5, ACTUAL = 0

I wrote these query, but it only updates row with the same ID or else inserts new one if there is no such ID

What you are looking for is called an upsert or in Oracle it is a merge.  When some condition is matched it would do an update but if it is not matched then it will do an insert. So for your scenario it would look something like
MERGE INTO documents d
USING (
    SELECT :new_id AS id,
           :new_person_id AS person_id,
           :new_doc_type AS doc_type,
           :new_doc_invalidity_id AS doc_invalidity_id,
           :new_doc_invalidity_date AS doc_invalidity_date,
           :new_actual AS actual
    FROM dual
) new_data
ON (d.PERSON_ID = new_data.person_id AND d.DOC_TYPE = new_data.doc_type)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET d.DOC_INVALIDITY_ID = 1,
               d.DOC_INVALIDITY_DATE = SYSDATE,
               d.ACTUAL = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ID, PERSON_ID, DOC_TYPE, DOC_INVALIDITY_ID, DOC_INVALIDITY_DATE, ACTUAL)
    VALUES (new_data.id, new_data.person_id, new_data.doc_type, new_data.doc_invalidity_id, new_data.doc_invalidity_date, new_data.actual)

